# ChatFormController BorderLayout CENTER does not work , Ant-Problem

Tags: chatroom

https://www.codenameone.com/blog/rad-chatroom-part-1.html

compiler error - eclipse - ChatFormController e.g. link

```
     super(parent);
     Form f = new Form("My First Chat Room", new BorderLayout());


    ChatRoomView view = new ChatRoomView(createViewModel(), f);

    f.add(CENTER, view) ;    

     setView(f);
 }
```